# How to create circular animation with different objects using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animation, geometry

How to create circular animation with different objects using jQuery. I have tried myself but the issue is that my scrip is not running smoothly.

I want this animate but in smooth way:

[image]

**Efforts** :
    http://jsfiddle.net/eT7SD/

Html Code

```
<div id="apDiv1"><p><img src="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/_UkDBPY_EcP4/TUr43iCI-FI/AAAAAAAADR0/o9rAgCt9d-U/s1600/1242796868203109724Number_1_in_green_rounded_square_svg_med.png"  width="200" height="115" id="img-1"/></p></div>
<div id="apDiv2"><p><img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRZv4hqGcyV6OqP0hI3uAiQVwHHgPuqcTl2NppFRyvbxXLVokbs"  width="200" height="115" id="img-2"/></p></div>
<div id="apDiv3"><p><img src="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQaplzZIaF-uTQKnvfK9N9i-Rg27F6aHtSchQZaGR-DITgO1bDwzA"  width="200" height="115" id="img-3"/></p></div>
<div id="apDiv4"><p><img src="https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQjTbe5WfEnT840gIChKfbzlVnoPPoZsyrT4zjMReym9YpsRdOFvA"  width="200" height="115" id="img-4"/></p></div>
<div id="apDiv5"><p><img src="https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRWtiMAcxGe-RQw2gRwUUiyB5aRTMeVMG5LSCPF0Qpzes-USpgyTw"  width="200" height="115" id="img-5"/></p></div>
<div id="apDiv6"><p><img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTXDhOygDcNsNVsv0eIXLYdBx4C-tmedIRhFfxGlCoCfNy04YU_"  width="200" height="115" id="img-6"/></p></div>
<div id="apCenterDiv"><img src="https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR42cgsKsYMWey79jT0XsTkMOyxc9oej9fVt-udxQvnVFOadpPQ"  width="200" height="115" /></div>
```

Css Code

```
<style type="text/css">
#apCenterDiv {
    position:absolute;
    width:200px;
    height:115px;
    z-index:1;
    left: 571px;
    top: 209px;
}
#apDiv1 {
    position:absolute;
    width:200px;
    height:115px;
    z-index:2;
    left: 570px;
    top: 4px;
}
#apDiv2 {
    position:absolute;
    width:200px;
    height:115px;
    z-index:3;
    left: 821px;
    top: 134px;
}
#apDiv3 {
    position:absolute;
    width:200px;
    height:115px;
    z-index:4;
    left: 822px;
    top: 328px;
}
#apDiv4 {
    position:absolute;
    width:200px;
    height:115px;
    z-index:5;
    left: 572px;
    top: 385px;
}
#apDiv5 {
    position:absolute;
    width:200px;
    height:115px;
    z-index:6;
    left: 319px;
    top: 329px;
}
#apDiv6 {
    position:absolute;
    width:200px;
    height:115px;
    z-index:7;
    left: 319px;
    top: 135px;
}
</style>
```

Script

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(e) {

      setInterval(function() {

        var imgfirstSrc = $("#img-1").attr("src");
        var imgSecSrc = $("#img-2").attr("src");
        var imgthirdSrc = $("#img-3").attr("src");
        var imgfourthSrc = $("#img-4").attr("src");
        var imgfifthSrc = $("#img-5").attr("src");
        var imgsixthSrc = $("#img-6").attr("src");


        $("#img-2").attr("src",imgfirstSrc);
        $("#img-3").attr("src",imgSecSrc);
        $("#img-4").attr("src",imgthirdSrc);
        $("#img-5").attr("src",imgfourthSrc);
        $("#img-6").attr("src",imgfifthSrc);
        $("#img-1").attr("src",imgsixthSrc);



      },1000);
});
</script>
```

**EDIT**

I have to add more animation with click/stop events. When user click the red image place of 270 they have to replace the place of 90 and animation will be stop; for more clarification you have to see the image below. I have tried `@Cristi Pufu` code but I want more modification

Efforts
http://jsfiddle.net/SaNtf/

[image]

Comment: do you want it to spin? or just change positions

Comment: @Spokey hmmm yes .... any idea ?

Comment: I don't think "yes" answers @Spokey 's question

Comment: You're going to need to use some sine and cosine functions to determine the coords of where the images should go.

Comment: @LeeTaylor sound interesting but sorry to say i have no idea, which approach is right. You have any idea regarding my problem please help me

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using `jQuery Animation`: http://jsfiddle.net/eT7SD/6/

Using `math`and `jQuery` : http://jsfiddle.net/eT7SD/7/

Using `CSS3 Rotation` (just for fun): http://jsfiddle.net/dMnKX/

Just add a `class` 'box' to your animating `divs` like in the `fiddle` and use this `js`:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {

    var animate = function(){

        var boxes = $('.box');

        $.each(boxes, function(idx, val){

            var coords = $(boxes[idx+1]).position() || $(boxes[0]).position();

            $(val).animate({

                "left" : coords.left,
                "top" : coords.top

            }, 1500, function(){})   

        });
    }

    animate();

    var timer = setInterval(animate, 2000);  
});
```

**EDIT**:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    var angles = [90, 45, 315, 270, 225, 135];
    var unit = 215;

    var animate = function(){

        $.each($('.box'), function(idx, val){

            var rad = angles[idx] * (Math.PI / 180);
            $(val).css({
                left: 550 + Math.cos(rad) * unit + 'px',
                top: unit * (1 - Math.sin(rad))  + 'px'
            });

            angles[idx]--;
        });

    }
    var timer = setInterval(animate, 10);

});
```

You have to change the `left`, `top`, `width`, `height` properties of boxes, standardize them, set the correct `unit` (`circle radius`) and initial `angles`. But for a preview, i think this is what you want (just needs a little more work).

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/eT7SD/7/

Visual understanding of angles:

[image: circle angles]

Comment: Check this url http://effinroot.eiremedia.netdna-cdn.com/repo/plugins/forms-controls/jquery-knob/index.html 

You did marvelous job but i want more smoother like above url, if you can do it for me i will thank to you with accept answer

Comment: Thankyou for edit your answer but i have an other query how to add more images `var angles = [90, 45, 315, 270, 225, 135,value,value];`

Comment: A circle has 360 degrees. Let's say you have 10 images. So 360 / 10 = 36 degrees between images. The top center image has about 90 degrees, so reporting to that, calculate the rest of the angles. I added a picture for better understanding

Comment: i added stop/start events so you know how to make it stop. http://jsfiddle.net/SaNtf/1/

Comment: when user click the angle of 270 the animation will be start after that angle of 270 reached angle of 90 the animation will be stop, rest of the angles animation perform aswell

Comment: i am a little busy at work right now, so maybe later or tommorow i'll try to help you. Sorry but i can't do all the work for you

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/SaNtf/3/ set the finalAngle, and when you click a box it will stop there.

Comment: You did Marvelous job, i know thank you is not enough for this but in the end of this discussion thank you... i hope in future, we will discuss again an another Question so take care and bye

Comment: glad i could help. take care

Comment: This is great help. very nice one. I want to follow your math example however if I use all divs as relative animation keeps on leave places and go in the bottom gradually. I want it responsive i.e. if my page width changes it should be always in center of the page. any idea how I can do this?

Answer (score 4):

Just use CSS3 to rotate the image:

html

```
<div id='container'>
... (all your images here)
</div>
```

javascript:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
window.myRotation=0;
$(document).ready(function(e) {
      setInterval(function() {
        $("#container").css("transform","rotate(" + window.myRotation + "deg)");
        $("#container").css("-ms-transform","rotate(" + window.myRotation + "deg)");
        $("#container").css("-webkit-transform","rotate(" + window.myRotation + "deg)");
        window.myRotation +=20;
      },50);
});
</script>
```

Comment: You should change `.attr` to `.css`.

Answer (score 1):

Well I tried out something, I think it could work
**NOTE:** *this is not the complete code and only an example of how it could work*

FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/Spokey/eT7SD/2/
**NEW FIDDLE** http://jsfiddle.net/Spokey/eT7SD/3/ (6 images)

I used .`position()` from jQuery to get the positions of `div1 - div6`.
 Then moved the image there using `.animate()`.

http://api.jquery.com/position/
http://api.jquery.com/animate/

**HTML**

```
<img src="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/_UkDBPY_EcP4/TUr43iCI-FI/AAAAAAAADR0/o9rAgCt9d-U/s1600/1242796868203109724Number_1_in_green_rounded_square_svg_med.png"  width="200" height="115" id="img-1"/>
<img src="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/_UkDBPY_EcP4/TUr43iCI-FI/AAAAAAAADR0/o9rAgCt9d-U/s1600/1242796868203109724Number_1_in_green_rounded_square_svg_med.png"  width="200" height="115" id="img-2"/>
<div id="apDiv1"></div>
<div id="apDiv2"></div>
<div id="apDiv3"></div>
<div id="apDiv4"></div>
<div id="apDiv5"></div>
<div id="apDiv6"></div>
<div id="apCenterDiv"></div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
      var i = 1;
        var j = 2;
      setInterval(function() {
          if(i===7){i=1;}
          if(j===7){j=1;} 
          var divd = $("#apDiv"+i).position();
          var divds = $("#apDiv"+j).position();
          $("#img-1").stop().animate({left:(divd.left), top:(divd.top)});
          $("#img-2").stop().animate({left:(divds.left), top:(divds.top)});
          i++;j++;
      },1000);
});
```

Comment: hey @Spokey how to add more can you please update you Js Fiddle

Comment: I updated it. The code isn't very nice looking but it works, I think you can optimize it in a few lines but I don't have enough time now.