# Need animation while scrolling the image in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to scroll all images on button click .And I want to stop scrolling of images when press stop 
Button.I have number of images on circle I want to scroll all images .
I google it find the best solution .Actually I am not able to integrate it on my code.

Here is the solution of my problem 
[How to create circular animation with different objects using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15947070/how-to-create-circular-animation-with-different-objects-using-jquery)

here is my fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/yQ8RQ/3/

I want to integrate this with my fiddle.can you please help me.

```
<button id ='start'>start</button>
<button id='stop'>stop</button>
<div>

<img src="https://dl.dropbox.com/s/66ip1iz8cm3wf2l/dial.png" style="position:absolute;top:=;left:;" id="dial"></img>
    <img src="https://dl.dropbox.com/s/siqq3e8kdaefqn8/icon_0.png" style="position:absolute;top:60px;left:190px;" id="dial"></img>

    <img src="https://dl.dropbox.com/s/zikxwpakha2ei1v/icon_1.png" style="position:absolute;top:100px;left:100px;" id="dial"></img>
    <img src="https://dl.dropbox.com/s/dn5n76r6yr1tzpd/icon_2.png" style="position:absolute;top:180px;left:70px;" id="dial"></img>
    <img src="https://dl.dropbox.com/s/vu9uckyoo7k8wcc/icon_3.png" style="position:absolute;top:270px;left:70px;" id="1"></img>
    <img src="https://dl.dropbox.com/s/lnb9h4hazcd619u/icon_4.png" style="position:absolute;top:370px;left:110px;" id="dial"></img>
    <img src="https://dl.dropbox.com/s/pt0q3zbdxt3843d/icon_5.png" style="position:absolute;top:420px;left:230px;" id="dial"></img>
    <img src="https://dl.dropbox.com/s/j9ybktafm0v08ff/icon_6.png" style="position:absolute;top:350px;left:340px;" id="dial"></img>
    <img src="https://dl.dropbox.com/s/nuh0njoeczd94gm/icon_7.png" style="position:absolute;top:250px;left:390px;" id="dial"></img>

    <div>
```

**Best solution is this..**
http://jsfiddle.net/SaNtf/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your fiddle is simply empty, please for the future show some effort and try something see: http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx.

You have to change your images id to be unique. Than you can set your images in the `boxes` object array, than change a bit the code of `unit` and the set of left and top values.

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    var timer = null;
    var animating = false;
    var unit = 200;

    var boxes = [
            {
                selector: '#dial2',
                angle: 90,
                finalAngle: 90,
                stop: false,
            },
            {
                selector: '#dial3',
                angle: 45,
                finalAngle: 90,
                stop: false,
            },
            {
                selector: '#dial4',
                angle: 315,
                finalAngle: 90,
                stop: false,
            },
            {
                selector: '#dial5',
                angle: 270,
                finalAngle: 90,
                stop: false,
            },
            {
                selector: '#dial6',
                angle: 225,
                finalAngle: 90,
                stop: false,
            },
            {
                selector: '#dial7',
                angle: 135,
                finalAngle: 90,
                stop: false,
            },
            {
                selector: '#dial8',
                angle: 0,
                finalAngle: 90,
                stop: false,
            },
            {
                selector: '#1',
                angle: 180,
                finalAngle: 90,
                stop: false,
            }
        ];

    $.each(boxes, function(idx, val){
        val.currentAngle = val.angle;

        $(val.selector).on('click', function(){ 
            if (!val.stop){
                console.log('box: ' + val.selector + ' will stop');
                val.stop = true;
            }
        });
    });

    var checkStop = function(){
        var stop = true;
        $.each(boxes, function(idx, val){
            if (!boxes[idx].stopped){
                stop = false;
            }
        });
        return stop;      
    };

    var animate = function(){

        $.each(boxes, function(idx, val){

            if (!boxes[idx].stopped){

                var rad = boxes[idx].currentAngle * (Math.PI / 180);

                $(boxes[idx].selector).css({
                    left: 225 + Math.cos(rad) * unit + 'px',
                    top: unit * (1 - Math.sin(rad)) +40 + 'px'
                });
                if (((boxes[idx].finalAngle - boxes[idx].currentAngle) % 360 == 0) && boxes[idx].stop == true){
                    boxes[idx].stopped = true;
                } 
                boxes[idx].currentAngle--;
            }

        });

        if (checkStop()){
             clearInterval(timer);   
        }
    }

    timer = setInterval(animate, 20);

});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/Krukd/1

Comment: sorry sir..But so one more thing,..!!

Comment: smh... @user944513 you'll never learn to program if everyone does everything for you.

Comment: But sir I  know jquery and javascript but I don't know the animation

Comment: I also search on google that why I posted the solution.But you give me negative feedback this not fare because in future I am not able to ask question because system block me

Comment: I'm not the downvoter. If you want to write a good question show what have you tried and post some code. See: http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx

Comment: If user want to scroll only shift one element left or right .on touchmove event can it is possible

Comment: Yes it's possible, you can implement it using the code that you have provided

Comment: but on "touchmove", or "swipeleft" or "swiperight" timer not work

Comment: you want to change poston of top or left?

Comment: I don't understand what you want to achieve, can you elaborate better please?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36888/discussion-between-user944513-and-irvin-dominin-aka-edward)