# How to create circular animation image using JQUERY using Mouseover /TouchStart /Mouseend/touchend?

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I am creating the circular animation of image while roatating .I take help from this url:
[How to create circular animation with different objects using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15947070/how-to-create-circular-animation-with-different-objects-using-jquery).
But I am able to rotate using start and stop button .Now I need to rotate image when user mouse over circularly and stop when mouse end ? is it possible ?

here is fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/Krukd/1/

```
<button id='start'>start</button>
<button id='stop'>stop</button>
<div>
    <img src="https://dl.dropbox.com/s/66ip1iz8cm3wf2l/dial.png" style="position:absolute;top:=;left:;" id="dial1"></img>
    <img src="https://dl.dropbox.com/s/siqq3e8kdaefqn8/icon_0.png" style="position:absolute;top:60px;left:190px;" id="dial2"></img>
    <img src="https://dl.dropbox.com/s/zikxwpakha2ei1v/icon_1.png" style="position:absolute;top:100px;left:100px;" id="dial3"></img>
    <img src="https://dl.dropbox.com/s/dn5n76r6yr1tzpd/icon_2.png" style="position:absolute;top:180px;left:70px;" id="dial4"></img>
    <img src="https://dl.dropbox.com/s/vu9uckyoo7k8wcc/icon_3.png" style="position:absolute;top:270px;left:70px;" id="1"></img>
    <img src="https://dl.dropbox.com/s/lnb9h4hazcd619u/icon_4.png" style="position:absolute;top:370px;left:110px;" id="dial5"></img>
    <img src="https://dl.dropbox.com/s/pt0q3zbdxt3843d/icon_5.png" style="position:absolute;top:420px;left:230px;" id="dial6"></img>
    <img src="https://dl.dropbox.com/s/j9ybktafm0v08ff/icon_6.png" style="position:absolute;top:350px;left:340px;" id="dial7"></img>
    <img src="https://dl.dropbox.com/s/nuh0njoeczd94gm/icon_7.png" style="position:absolute;top:250px;left:390px;" id="dial8"></img>
    <div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear when you want to start / stop the animation -- the easiest way is to give the surrounding `div` an id (`container` for example) and set the size of it. Then bind the mouse events to that. Since you already have an image that covers the whole thing you can use that:

```
$("#dial1").mouseenter(function () {
    timer = setInterval(animate, 20);
});

$("#dial1").mouseleave(function () {
    clearInterval(timer);
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SpaceDog/sFcCU/)

For touch events you can do something similar, have a look at this answer for more about touch events: [How to recognize touch events using jQuery in Safari for iPad? Is it possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4755505/how-to-recognize-touch-events-using-jquery-in-safari-for-ipad-is-it-possible)

However, if you only want the animation to run when you're over the circle of icons you'll have to do something else. In this case you'd use the `mouseover` event and call a function that does the following (psuedocode)

```
Get current pointer postion, calculate distance from center of the circle
IF (pointer distance > circle radius)
    IF (animation is running) THEN stop animation
ELSE 
    IF (animation is not running) THEN start animation
```

Alternatively define an image map to control the active area (where you want the animation to run) and attach the handlers to that.